# Distince session variable with same name from different php application

Tags: php, session, server-side

I have two PHP applications. Each of them use a different set of session variables, but some of them have the same name, and the server treats them as one session variable. So, how can I make the server treats them as different variables. Of course, the two application is sharing one hosting. And I don't know whether my using of the term `PHP application` is wrong or right in this situation, if wrong, sorry about that. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use session_name before calling session_start. Use a different name for each application. [session_name](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.session-name.php)